# Relativistic particle in circular motion

Tags: special-relativity, classical-mechanics

Imagine a relativistic particle in a circular motion, e.g. electron in magnetic field. We can easily obtain the centripetal acceleration in laboratory frame using : $$F= evB = \frac{dp}{dt} = \frac{d(\gamma mv)}{dt} = \gamma ma\;\Rightarrow a = \frac{evB}{\gamma m}.$$ From there we can use $a = \frac{v^2}{r}$ to obtain radius of motion $r = \frac{\gamma mv}{eB}$, as well as period of orbit $T = \frac{2r\pi}{v} = \frac{2\pi eB}{\gamma mv}$. My question is what is the radius and period of motion in the reference frame of electron ($r'$, $T'$). Intuitively, I would just imagine that $r'=r/\gamma$ and $T' = T\gamma$ because we could apply Lorentz transformations for each instantenous position of the electron, and because $v$ is constant each small section of the path is contracted by the same factor. But on the other hand, I'm afraid this is too symplistic and I'm not sure if the fact that electron is moving in the non inertial reference frame somehow complicates things.

Comment: If you transform from the lab frame to the rest frame of the electron at a particular instance then the velocity of the centre from the electron's perspective is (at that moment) perpendicular to the position vector of the centre. So I would *not* expect the naive length contraction... tl;dr We should work out the solution carefully.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Hmm, I think I see your point. In the meantime I found this paper which I think implies (if I didn't grossly misinterpret something, which could be the case) that relation is indeed a simple contraction factor : https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/12/9/011/pdf         
But obviously, I think my line of thinking about this was wrong.

Comment: In the electron’s frame, the electron is at rest, so I don’t see what you mean by the period and radius of its trajectory. Don’t you rather mean the radius and period of the trajectory of the center about which it rotates when viewed in the original inertial frame ?

Comment: @lpz Yes, that's what I meant

Comment: If you understand french, here is a nice visualization of [relativistic circular motion](https://youtu.be/bVBxSxcgdro) (I’ll write and answer with some maths)

Comment: @lpz Unfortunately I don't understand french. Automatic translation to english allowed me to understand the approach but it's not super clear as I imagine a lot has been lost/misguided in translation.